# wireguard killswitch is not properly working for me

Tags: networking, network-interface, vpn, wireguard

I have a server on where I use wireguard. On this server I have a killswitch set up which seem to be working properly in case the wireguard connection drops.

But when I update my ubuntu 22.04 server it asks which application I want to restart. For example I just restarted these

```
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
 systemctl restart virtlogd.service
Service restarts being deferred:
 systemctl restart libvirtd.service
 systemctl restart multipathd.service
 systemctl restart packagekit.service
 systemctl restart polkit.service
 systemctl restart ssh.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
 systemctl restart systemd-machined.service
 systemctl restart usbguard.service
 systemctl restart user@1000.service
```

When I check my IP after I updated my system and did the above restart, I get my server IP as return. But it seems wireguard is still up and running. When I start wireguard it tells me the conf is up and running.

Now when put wg down I get a different output than normally (I masked my IP with a random IP)

```
$ sudo wg-quick down wg0
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -d tun.wg0 -f
[#] iptables-restore -n
[#] ip rule del from 44.212.174.12 lookup VPN; ip ro del 44.212.174.0/24 dev ens10f0np0 table VPN; ip ro del default via 44.212.174.1 dev ens10f0np0 table VPN
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

What is this `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`?

Now when I do wg-quick up and down everything is ok. Why my killswitch breaks when I restart a few processes?

I'm aware of this problem and always start my wg connection after updating. But this doesn't solve the issue. Sometimes after a couple of weeks the killswitch breaks without updating at all. I get the same error when I put wg down.

Anyone have an idea what causes this problem and how to solve it?